# How to convert a 5 digit INT used as time and display it as HH:MM:SS in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on a data query and one of my fields has a time format of '33600' and is a data type (INT).  I need to know how to convert the field so that it displays the correct time format of HH:MM:SS.   The current query I used gives me the date/time as MM/DD/YYYY:00:00:00.

Ex:  Convert(datetime,Cast(Ap.aptApptTime as varchar(6),3)as Appt_time

This produces the correct appointment date but gives 00:00:00 for the time.  I need to display just the correct time based on a value like '33600'.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the "correct" time for `33600`?

Comment: Is 33600 to be interpreted as 03:36:00?

Answer (score 2):

If 33600 is a count of milliseconds, this should work.

```
DECLARE @Var TIME = '00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(MS, 33600, @Var)
```

If seconds;

```
DECLARE @Var TIME = '00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(S, 33600, @Var)
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 33600 is the number of seconds, you could also try

```
Cast(Cast((33600/86400.0) as smalldatetime) as time)
```

Where `86400.0` is the total number of seconds in a day. Don't forget the ".0" or SQL will treat it as an integer and the result will always be zero or midnight. You also can't cast directly from a number to a time field, so you have to use an intermediate smalldatetime field.